# ERROR: plan should not reference subplan's variable, how to solve it? postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do this select in postgresSQL and It gives me this error:

> ERROR: plan should not reference subplan's variable
>   SQL state: XX000

I don't know how I can solve this, I tested and all in my table is correct....

```
select distinct concat(concat(ID,'_'), ID_DEV), EXTERNAL_URL, LAST_UPDATED,
from NOISE
where concat(concat(ID,'_'), ID_DEV) not in (select distinct  concat(concat(ID,'_'), ID_DEV)
                                                   from NOISE
                                                   where upload_time < (select max(UP_TIME) from NOISE order by max(UP_TIME) desc fetch first row only) )
```

Comment: You should send the real query along with the table definitions. The query that you present does not cause that error.

Comment: `concat(concat(ID,'_'), ID_DEV)` is a terrible way to perform a join on a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try first:

```
select distinct concat(concat(ID,'_'), ID_DEV), 
        EXTERNAL_URL, LAST_UPDATED,
  from NOISE n
 where (ID, ID_DEV) not in 
       (select (n1.ID, n1.ID_DEV)
          from NOISE n1
         where upload_time < 
               (select max(n2.UP_TIME) 
                  from NOISE n2)
```

There is no point to the ordering by max since you aren't grouping and you know with the aggregate it will be just one row anyway.  It's still a bit hairy of a query.....